# requiring the value of `xsi:type` to be a type in a specific namespace regardless of prefix

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

Say I have the following XML file:

```
<A xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:foo="http://foo"
   xsi:type="foo:SomeSubtypeOfA">
    boo
</A>
```

I wish to require that the XML instance is of a specific type derived from `A`, e.g. type `{http://foo}SomeSubtypeOfA` (as indeed the above example is). So I am using the following XPath:

```
/*[@xsi:type='foo:SomeSubtypeOfA']
```

... and check whether it succeeds in returning a node or not. However the XPath above is problematic as it relies on the arbitrary prefix so it fails on the following file:

```
<A xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:foo2="http://foo"
   xsi:type="foo2:SomeSubtypeOfA">
    boo
</A>
```

... and it produces a false match on the following file:

```
<A xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:foo="http://fooX"
   xsi:type="foo:SomeSubtypeOfA">
    boo
</A>
```

To get rid of the false match I could write the XPath as:

```
/*[namespace::foo[.='http://foo'] and @xsi:type='foo:SomeSubtypeOfA']
```

But that still fails to account for the possibility of some other prefix bound to the `http://foo` namespace. How can I write the above XPath so it checks the namespace of the type given in the `xsi:type` attribute rather than its prefix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XPath 2.0 you can do

```
/*[namespace-uri-from-QName(resolve-QName(@xsi:type, .)) = 'http://foo' and local-name-from-QName(resolve-QName(@xsi:type, .)) = 'SomeSubtypeOfA']
```

In XPath 1.0 you need to do something like

```
//*[namespace::*[name()=substring-before(../@xsi:type, ':')] = 'http://foo/']
```

(but that probably doesn't allow for the type being in the default namespace)